# python function to reduce logical operators and operands in a list

Tags: python, list, logical-operators

I have  the following list.

```
op=[[3,4,5],'or',[5,6,7],'or',[8,9,10],'and',[9,10,11],'and',[10,11,12]]
```

This list has lists and operators('and','or') which need to be reduced.

All the 'and' operations need to be done first finally leaving just the 'or'.
As follows:
The list after

```
step 1: [[3,4,5],'or',[5,6,7],'or',[8,9,10],'and',[10,11]]
step 2: [[3,4,5],'or',[5,6,7],'or' ,[10]]
step 3: [[3,4,5],'or',[5,6,7,10]]
step 4: [[3,4,5,6,7,10]]
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Sonia

Comment: please, add your own code, what you have attempt and where you're stuck

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: actually i just working on this. no idea how to proceed.

Comment: im a beginner in python programming

Comment: It seems you are trying to do set intersections and unions. For this there is the built in [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) type.

Comment: In python,'and','or' are Boolean operators.You maybe need to use set.

Comment: but i need to apply a logic to follow the order of operation

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to make two functions, one for 'and' and one for 'or'. Here is my suggestion for 'or':

```
def Or(iter1, iter2):
    set1 = set(iter1)
    set1.add(iter2)
    return list(set1)
```

For 'and':

```
def And(iter1, iter2):
    lst1 = []
    for iterable in iter1:
        if iterable in iter2:
            lst1.append(iterable)
    return lst1
```

Then, you'd just have to have some sort of function that loops through the list, and if it finds an 'and', it runs the `And` function on the element before it and the element after it, the same for the `Or` function. This looks like it's your Python homework, so the rest I'll leave to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt!

This approach uses recursion. The print statement can be used to verify each step if I understood the problem as intended. Some shortcomings of this code are the two calls to pop (not elegant) and the double for loop. But based on my understanding of the problem, it does seem to do the job.

```
def main(op):
  print(op)
  if len(op) > 1: 
     for i in range(0, len(op)): 
        if op[i] == "and":
             new_ele = set(op[i-1]).intersection(set(op[i+1]))
             op[i-1] = new_ele
             op.pop(i)
             op.pop(i)
             main(op)
     for i in range(0, len(op)): 
        if op[i] == "or":
            new_ele = set(op[i-1]).union(set(op[i+1]))
            op[i-1] = new_ele
            op.pop(i)
            op.pop(i)
            print(op)
            main(op)

main(op)
print(op)
```

Suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my own way to implement it.
Thanks for all of you for working hard on this.
Pls go through my solution too and let me know  if it seems fine.

Algorithm as follows:
1.separate the whole list into 2. One for operands(list lovop) and other for operators(list op).

```
2.  

    while 'and' in op:
            j = op.index(7)
            print("index", j)
            # print(lovop)
            fn(j, lovop)
            op.pop(j)
            print(lovop)
```

3.

```
def fn(ind,lsts):
    lsts[ind]=list(set(lsts[ind]) & set(lsts[ind+1]))
    lsts.pop(ind+1)
    return(lsts)
```

4.

```
filters = unionlist(lovop)
```

5.

```
def unionlist(lst):
    result=set()
    for i in lst:
        result=result | set(i)
    return(list(result))
```